# Does Google have a rate limit for Oauth API?

Tags: oauth, contacts, google-oauth

I am calling Google APIs using Oauth and pulling a user's contact info and contact photos. I ran into the same problems as the author of this blog where pulling photos counted against some API limit. Is there a way to increase this limit?

http://vincentwoo.com/2012/08/15/the-api-for-googles-most-valuable-resource-sucks/

Comment: Sorry, posted the wrong link, here is on oauth2: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2. I think you would have to contact google since that seems their policy on other APIs. If you hit the limit, you probably need to pay.